# IIS 7.5 rewriting module

Tags: url-rewriting, web-config, iis-7.5, redirect

I need your help on IIS 7.5 rewriting module.

These are what I have:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/products/94128/country/***city_name(on)/product_100%_name
http://www.mydomain.com/products/92105/country/.city(??)_name/product_n.a.m.e-
http://www.mydomain.com/products/21365/country/city,_name./?product_,/name_3*
```

Can I remove all unwanted characters and make clean url like this one:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/products/21365/country/city_name/product_name
```

Comment: Probably yes, what doesn't work with what you have tried?

Comment: I have no knowledge about it and open your suggestions..